# Why isn't this simple SQL query working? select *, count(*) from table

Tags: sql, select, count

I'm trying to learn SQL and am following along with an exercise, but I am hung up on why this simple SQL statement will not work.

`select *, count(*) from bricks`

What the instructor is trying to do is return all the rows of a table named bricks.  We also want to append a new column to the right side of the table that simply returns the total count of all bricks in each record.  So there are 6 bricks total in the table, so each row should have a column at the end that just reads 6.

The way that the instructor did it is by doing this:

`select b.*, (select count(*) from bricks) total_bricks_in_table from bricks b;`

The first query is my attempt at it and I don't see why it doesn't work seeing as running

`select * from bricks`

and

`select count(*) from bricks`

Each work on their own, but not when combined.  I've tried adding a group by statement to the end of my attempt but no matter which column I group by I still get errors.  What exactly is wrong with my original attempt?

Comment: Your 1st Select returns 6 rows and your 2nd 1 row, how should the DNMS combine that? If your DBMS supports *Windowed Aggregates*:  `select *, count(*) OVER () from bricks`

Comment: The syntax `select *, count(*) from bricks` is malformed. Beware, it's deprecated in MySQL 5.7.5 and newer (unless you enable old syntax) for a good reason.

Comment: @dnoeth I guess that makes sense, but then how come the other query with the nested select statement works?  To me it seems to be doing the same thing.  The inner select statement runs first and returns a single row with a value of 6, and that result is used in the outer select statement, right?  What is different about that one that makes it work?

Comment: The *inner select* is a *Scalar Subquery* which is logically executed for each row, but the optimizer is usually smart enough to see that it always returns the same value and executes it only once.

Comment: A single `*` may not be combined with anything else in the select list, according to ISO/ANSI SQL.

Comment: @dnoeth so are all subqueries/inner select statements deemed scalar subqueries by default?  I tried running ````select *, (select count(*) from bricks) from bricks```` and it still gives an error, so it seems that just tucking the count function in a subquery doesn't really help.

Comment: You can do `select bricks.*, (select count(*) ...`. (See my previous comment.)

Comment: @jarlh but isn't ````select *```` and ````select bricks.*```` the same thing when we only have one table?  i dont understand why adding the "bricks." prefix makes it work now when combined with the subquery, which also has a *  ....

Comment: As jarlh wrote, you must qualify the `*` with a table name/alias. Some DBMSes allow `select *,...`, relaxing Standard SQL syntax

Answer (score 3):

It is because `COUNT` is an aggregate function, and once you use one aggregate, you have to choose how to aggregate every other columns of your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: So how do I go about choosing how to aggregate all the columns?  Wouldn't that be done by using the GROUP BY clause?  As I've stated I've already tried that and keep getting errors.  Also, the instructor's statement does not use group by and still works.

Comment: In fact it doesn't make much sense (in SQL that is) to have the total count on each line of result. In fact the database can't do that as it'll have to iterate through all records to do so. So if you group everything, you'll end up with 1 as a result of the count for each line. If you still want that total count on each line, I'll use a sub-select like you did, which isn't efficient, but will do the trick for you.

Comment: Also try @dnoeth comment, if your DBMS allows it, it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
select *, count(*)
from bricks
```

is malformed.  Because of the `count()` this is an *aggregation* query.  An aggregation query with no `group by` *always* returns one row.  However, you are also trying to select other columns -- any reasonable database will follow the SQL standard and return an error.

What can you do?  SQL has something called window functions.  This makes it quite simple to do what you want:

```
select *, count(*) over () as num_bricks
from bricks
```